# When executing the create-materialized-view query in ADX Cluster , getting error related to the caching policy

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to execute the following command  of ADX cluster with backfill property set, then operation id is getting returned :

```
   .create async ifnotexists materialized-view with (backfill=true, docString="Asset Trends") AssetTrend on table Variables
{
Variables 
| where variable == 'severity' and model=='conditionMonitor' and 
  timestamp between (datetime(2022-06-29) .. 1d) 
| summarize Normal = countif(value<=1), CheckSUM = countif(value>1 and 
  value<=250), OutofSpecification = countif(value>250 and value<=500),
   MaintenanceRequired = countif(value>500 and value<=750), 
   Failure = countif(value>750 and value<=1000) 
   by bin(timestamp,1s)
}
```

I am getting the following error :
[image]
Please let me know how can I fix this.

Comment: **(1)** You are running a command, not a query. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/ **(2)** The query part of your command is invalid for MV. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create **(3)** "it is coming as cancelled" is not an operation state, nor status. **(4)** read about `operations`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/operations

Comment: Yes , it is a command . But materialized view is not getting created when I am executing the command . Also , when I am executing the AssetTrend1234  , then it is showing error :  '' operator: Failed to resolve table or column or scalar expression named 'AssetTrend1234  '. I am able to create materialized view once and post that I am facing this issue .

Comment: I tried the following query and the issue is still the same : .create async ifnotexists materialized-view with (backfill=true, docString="Asset Trends") AssetTrend on table Variables
{
Variables 
| where variable == 'severity'  and 
  timestamp between (datetime(2022-06-29) .. 1d) 
| summarize Normal = countif(value<=1), CheckSUM = countif(value>1 and 
  value<=250), OutofSpecification = countif(value>250 and value<=500),
   MaintenanceRequired = countif(value>500 and value<=750), 
   Failure = countif(value>750 and value<=1000) 
   by bin(timestamp,1s)
}

Comment: I have updated the query for better reference in the question also . I am still facing the same issue . Please review .

Answer (score 1):

- The solution was given to you in the error message:

> An admin command cannot be executed due to an invalid state:
> State='Materialized view creation with backfill option is not
> supported for tables with extents in cold cache.  **Please increase the
> hot cache policy to cover all extents in table or create the view with
> no backfill'**

- The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create#backfill-a-materialized-view) states the same, plus an additional tip:

> Using the backfill option is not supported for data in cold cache.
> Increase the hot cache period, if necessary, for the duration of the
> view creation. **This may require scale-out**.

[Cache policy (hot and cold cache)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/cachepolicy)

Comment: Kind reminder to check the answer